# ConcurrentHashMap removing thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrenthashmap

I'm now doing something with Java ConcurrentHashMap.
I have some trouble with multi-thread environment.

My code is : 
1. Adding Runnable object to ConcurrentHashMap.

```
private Map<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AA();
    }
};
ScheduledFuture<?> task = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 10); 
scheduledTasks.put(taskId, task);
```

2. Removing Runnable object to ConcurrentHashMap.

```
    if (scheduledTasks.get(taskId) != null && !"".equals(scheduledTasks.get(taskId))
    {
        scheduledTasks.get(taskId).cancel(true);
        scheduledTasks.get(taskId).remove();
    }
```

Just adding or removing does not cause a problem, and if I print `scheduledTasks.keySet()` to the console or log file, it prints the correct result.

**However, the problem is that after runnable object removed from Map, some runnable objects are still running(Even though Map no longer has that runnable object !).**

I am really not sure what the problem is here. Is my understanding of 'Java multi-thread environment' lacking? Or... this problem is about `ScheduledFuture`?

Comment: Why would removing a thread from a map stop its execution?

Comment: Basically what @RobbyCornelissen asked. `ConcurrentHashMap` is a data structure with thread safety, it says nothing about executing tasks. In other words, removing the task from the map does not stop the task execution, and does not delete the scheduled runnable either (there is no garbage collection since being scheduled means something else has a reference to it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way as well:

```
ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
CountDownLatch taskLatch = new CountDownLatch(10);
List<Callable Interface Instance> loadingTasks = new ArrayList<Callable Interface Instance>();
//create instance of Callable Interface Instance
loadingTasks.add(task);// where task will be Callable Interface Instance/reference name

List<Future<Boolean>> futures = exe.invokeAll(loadingTasks);
boolean complete = taskLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); //waiting for tasks to be completed

for (Future<Boolean> f : futures) {
taskComplete = f.get(); //get callable interface instance call method return value
}
```